# Geopy Always Returns NoneType Object for Address

Tags: python, geopy, nominatim

I am new to geocoding and I am trying to work with the following address 1 IKEA WAYSTORE 027ISVADGZC,ROUND ROCK,TX 78664. Every time I use the Nominatim class in Geopy for this and every other address not only can I not get the latitude and longitude for the address, but none of the material I have found on stackoverflow or the documentation explains how to fix this issue in a detailed manner.

I have attempted some code for the address and have come up short.

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
address = '1 IKEA WAYSTORE 027ISVADGZC,ROUND ROCK,TX 78664'
geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent='<example email>')
location = geolocator.geocode(address, exactly_one=True)
print(location.latitude)
print(location.longitude)
```

Would it be possible to explain to me why this code is not returning the longitude and latitude and what specific solution I need to implement to get these attributes?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried searching in Nomatim directly?
For example at https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org
From what I can see it doesn't have this address.

Comment: Can you give me some reproducible examples of a geocoding method that works with this address?

Comment: How do you get the key? Is it free?

Comment: I'm trying to create a comment with some code... but without success

Comment: Try to replace Nomatim with TomTom. Get API key at [developer portal](https://developer.tomtom.com). You have free daily limit of 2500 transactions. One transaction = one geocoding.

Comment: did you succeed with this?

Comment: I haven’t had a chance to try it out yet

Comment: This one has helped me.